# smarty array index

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, smarty

I have an array

```
array('foo_1' => 1, 'bar_1' =>1, 'foo_2' => 2, 'bar_2' => 2, ... )

for($i = 1; $i<=12; $i++){
    echo $month['foo_'.$i];
}
```

And I don't understand how can I access the values from it using Smarty.

```
{counter start=0 skip=1 assign="i"}
 {section name = month start = 0 loop = 12 step = 1}
  {if isset($arr.foo_.$i)}
   {$arr.bar_$i}
  {/if}
  {counter}
 {/section}
```

But it doesn't work. The main issue is - How I can access array['foo_1']  in smarty ? Can you please help?

Comment: I'm not a PhP programmer, but isn't that a hash and not an array?

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr a HashTable is called an Array in PHP ;)

Comment: Do you mean a hash table? In PHP there aren't  any hash tables like in JAVA. However an array is a kind of hash table isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must build the key before accessing it in the array. Use assign to build the complete name.

```
{assign var=fooKey value="foo_"|cat:$i}
{assign var=barKey value="bar_"|cat:$i}
{if isset($arr.{$fooKey})}
  {$arr.{$barKey}}
{/if}
```

Your attempt `{$arr.foo_.$i}` means accessing the subkey `$i` in the array under `$arr.foo_`.